# Get all comments on a post by an array of users

Tags: php, wordpress, comments

I'm trying to get all the comments from a post by an array of users.

This is what I'd like to be able to do:

```
$user_ids = array(10, 22, 41, 80);
$post_id = 57;

$args = array (
    'number'   => -1,
    'user_id'  => $user_ids,
    'post_id'  => $post_id,
    'status'   => 'approve',
    'order'    => 'DESC'
);
$comments = get_comments( $args );
```

Now **obviously this doesn't work**, but that's what I'd like to do. Is there any other way to achieve this? Maybe using a custom select?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've built a WPDB query based on [the `query` method](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.2/wp-includes/comment.php#L210) of `WP_Comment_Query` class. And doing the sanitization based on [this forum post](http://wordpress-hackers.1065353.n5.nabble.com/WP-3-5-2-multisite-How-to-use-NOT-IN-in-wpdb-prepare-tp41812p41824.html).

```
global $wpdb;

// Sanitize
$post = '1148';
$post = absint($post);

// Sanitize
$a = '2'; // User One
$b = '3'; // User Two
$user_ids = array_map( 'absint', array( $a, $b ) );
$user_ids = implode( ', ', $user_ids );

$query = "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->comments 
        WHERE comment_post_ID = $post 
        AND user_id IN ($user_ids) 
        AND comment_approved = 1
        ORDER BY comment_date DESC";
$comments = $wpdb->get_results( $query );
```

Comment: This seems to work great. Does it put the latest comment into $comments[0]? I think it does, but don't see that in the SELECT so just checking with you.

Comment: Use `echo '<pre>' . print_r( $comments, true ) . '</pre>';` or a `var_dump( $comments )` to inspect its contents. I use [FirePHP](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/71599/12615) to debug.

Comment: Sorry for the poorly worded comment. I'll try again: Does this query respect the sort order by date descending?

Comment: This also doesn't seem to look for posts that are approved. What do I need to tweak to only get approved comments?

Answer (score 1):

A simple `SELECT` query would do:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->comments 
          WHERE comment_post_ID = %d 
             AND comment_approved = 1
             AND user_id IN %s
          ORDER BY comment_date DESC"; // get only approved comment and sort by date

$comments = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare(
    $query, 
    intval($post_id), 
    '('.implode(',', array_map('intval', $user_ids)).')'
)); // use prepare to prevent SQL injection
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I didn't even test with `wpdb->prepare`, as there was [this recent thread at \[wp-hackers\]](http://wordpress-hackers.1065353.n5.nabble.com/WP-3-5-2-multisite-How-to-use-NOT-IN-in-wpdb-prepare-tp41812p41824.html), I thought it would bug in this case too. Just out of curiosity, did you test this, Hieu? I tried it, and it returns `0` results...

Comment: No not really, possibly it would cause a bug too in my code too hmm

Answer (score 0):

We can use the `OR` condition in MySQL to do this.

If I was to write the query we want using the values you provided it could be done something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM comments WHERE comment_post_ID='57' AND (user_id='10' OR user_id='22' OR user_id='41' OR user_id='80')
```

Now, we can make this dynamic and processable by PHP:

```
// The User IDs and Post ID (make sure you are escaping these properly).
$user_ids = array(10, 22, 41, 80);
$post_id = 57;

foreach($user_ids as $uid){     $user_ids_string .= " OR user_id='$uid'";   }       // Loop through each user and append their ID to the query segment.
$user_ids_string = substr($use, 4);                                                 // Remove the unnecessary first " OR "

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE comment_post_ID='$post_id' AND ($user_ids_string)");     // Create the final MySQL Query.
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    // Do something with each $row[].
}
```

Before you use this, make sure you're connected to the WordPress database properly before using this and that all the tables and fields I've listed are correct for your installation first.

Answer (score 0):

paste this code in `functions.php`

```
function users_comment( $postid = null , $users = array() ){
    if( ! empty( $users ) && $postid ){

        foreach ($users as $user) {
            $args = array (
                'number'   => '',
                'user_id'  => $user,
                'post_id'  => $postid,
                'status'   => 'approve',
                'order'    => 'DESC'
            );
            $comments[] = get_comments( $args );
        }
    return $comments;
    }else{
        return 'Please provide a user id and postid';
    }
}
```

use this function anywhere you want by calling it required parameters user ids and post id.

```
print_r( users_comment(1,array(1,4,3)) );
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> only single user to get post:
> ```

```
$args = array(
    'status' => 'approve',
    'number' => '-1',
    'post_id' => 57,
        'user_id'  => 1,
        'order'    => 'DESC'
);
$comments = get_comments($args);
foreach($comments as $comment) :
    echo($comment->comment_author . '<br />' . $comment->comment_content);
endforeach;
?>
```

> For multiple user get comment using post id:

```
$args = array( 'user_id' => 0 );
add_filter( 'comments_clauses', 'custom_comments_clauses');
$comments = get_comments( $args );
remove_filter( 'comments_clauses', 'custom_comments_clauses');

function custom_comments_clauses( $clauses ){
    $clauses['where'] = str_replace( 'user_id = 0',
                       'user_id IN (1, 2, 3)',
                       $clauses['where'] );
    return $clauses;
}
```

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/105010/get-comments-only-for-certain-specific-users-in-template-file

Comment: You can't use an array for 'user_id' parameter in get_comments.

Comment: sorry, i have added before fist code only one user's comments getting so have a change added multiple user's comments get.

Answer (score 0):

As Brasofilo already provided you the custom query to get the comments but it will fetch all the comments while they were trashed

```
$user_ids = array(10, 22, 41, 80);
$post_id = 57;
global $wpdb;

$comments=$wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM `wp_comments` WHERE 
`comment_post_ID` =$post_id AND `user_id` IN (".join(',',$user_ids)")
 AND `comment_approved` ='1' ORDER BY `comment_date` DESC");
```