# Show only current user's wordpress comments on page

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a website where I created an "answer and get a reply" page using wordpress comments.

Where the user posts a comment and then the admin replies it (me)

What I want: This **logged in** user must see **only his comments** (questions) and admin's replies **(only the replies for his comments).**

What I achieved so far: I'm using this piece of code

```
<?php
        $user_id = get_current_user_id();
        $user_specific_comments = get_comments(
            array(
                'user_id' => $user_id,
            )
        );

        wp_list_comments(
            array(
                'per_page' => 10,
            ),

            $user_specific_comments
        );
        ?>
```

As you can see, it gets the current user's ID and displays only his comments, good.

But that's also the problem, by the ID, it shows **only** his comments and **not** admin replies!

When change *'user_id' => $user_id* to *'user_id' => array($user_id,1)*

*(1 = admin ID)*

Then it shows all his comments plus **all** admins comments posted for any other user.

What I want to achieve is: Show only comments posted for the **current user** plus only admin's **replies for his** comments.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Perhaps [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17636764/get-all-comments-on-a-post-by-an-array-of-users) will help you

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me! it does what I say above, it displays all comments from those IDs, I just want to display the current user's comments plus admin replies ONLY to his comments (and not replies to other comments or single admin comments)